# collectionview didselectitem returns wrong indexpath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

basically when i use the function didDeselectItemAt in my collectionview it returns the wrong values, here's the collectionview functions.
tried to change the buttons, tried to return different values also doesnt work, also something really weird happens is that it doesn't register the first click for any collectionviewcell for some reason.

```swift
let transactionTitles = ["Send Credit", "Request credit", "Scan QR-Code"]
let transactionImages = ["SendMoney", "RecieveMoney", "QRCode"]
var containerView = UIView()
let cellReuseIdentifier = "TransactionsNumPad"
let headerReuseIdentifier = "Header"
let numbersArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",".", "0", ""]
let imageArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","", "", "delete.left.fill"]

var dialedNumbersString = ""


//MARK: Collectionview Datasource
extension TransactionDatasrc: UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numbersArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)as? TransactionsNumPad else {return UICollectionViewCell()}
        cell.digitsLabel.text = numbersArray[indexPath.item]
        cell.lettersLabel.text = String(indexPath.item)
        
//        cell.backImage.image = UIImage(systemName: imageArray[indexPath.item])
        
        return cell
        
    }
}
//MARK: CollectionView Delegate
extension TransactionDatasrc: UICollectionViewDelegate {
//    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        if (indexPath.row != 0){
//            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)as? TransactionsNumPad else {return}
//            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1)
//            cell.digitsLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 32)
//        }
//    }
    
    //MARK: header dequeue
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        guard let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)as? DialedNumbersHeader else {return UICollectionReusableView()}
        
        header.ammountLabel.text = dialedNumbersString
        print(indexPath.item)
        
        return header
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: collectionView.width, height: collectionView.height / 4.5)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
////        let number = numbersArray[indexPath.item]
//        dialedNumbersString += String(indexPath.item)
//        collectionView.reloadData()
        print(indexPath)
    }

}

extension TransactionDatasrc: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let leftRightPadding = collectionView.frame.width * 0.15
        let interSpacing = collectionView.frame.width * 0.1
        let cellWidth = (collectionView.frame.width - 2 * leftRightPadding - 2 * interSpacing) / 3
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth , height: cellWidth)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        
        let leftRightPadding = collectionView.frame.width * 0.15
        
        return .init(top: 16, left: leftRightPadding, bottom: 16, right: leftRightPadding)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 16
    }
}
```

i tried to work on this for a while but had no luck, also tried to change some code, still doesn't work.

Comment: Would you clear that code a bit and tell us what  is being printed and what are you excpecting to be printed

Comment: Solved, I used didDeselctItemAt instead of didSelectItemAt.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell` in `didSelectItemAt`, it will case some cell reuse problem. Instread, you can have a try
by `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`.

I think it may help.